# get [object%20Object] error when using ajaxFileUpload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a javaScript script as follows:

```
$.ajaxFileUpload({
        url: url,
        secureuri: false, 
        fileElementId: ['upload-file'], 
        dataType: "JSON", 
        data:{ "sample_path":$(".demo-view-container-left .view img").attr("src")},
        success: function (data)  
        {
            data=JSON.parse(data);
            json = JSON.stringify(data.prediction, undefined, 4)
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var cxt=c.getContext("2d");
            var cxt_text=c.getContext("2d");
            for(var i=0; i<data.prediction.length; ++i){
              score_location=data.prediction[i][i.toString()]
              location=score_location['location']
              cxt.moveTo(location['left'], location['top']);
              cxt.lineTo(location['left']+location['width'], location['top']);
              cxt.lineTo(location['left']+location['width'], location['top']+location['height']);
              cxt.lineTo(location['left'], location['top']+location['height']);
              cxt.lineTo(location['left'], location['top']);
              cxt.stroke();
              cxt_text.font="12px";
              cxt_text.fillText(score_location['score'].toString(), location['left'], location['top']);
            }
            $(".demo-view-container-right p").html("预测JSON:<br>"+json)
        },
        error: function (data)
        {  
        }
```

It can go into `success` part and execute all lines, but finally it go to a new URL which is current URL appended `[object%20Object]`resulting in a 404 error. How to solve this problem?
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating away because the following line is

```
location=score_location['location'] <-- that is the line that is doing it.
```

location is pointing to widow.location so you are doing

```
window.location = { ... }
```

That is what happens when you do not use `var` and the variable has meaning on the window object. So declare it

```
var location = score_location['location']
```

Comment: @AndrewGong If this answer solved your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick below the downvote arrow.